# problem with 2 usb gamepad connection and settings

Tags: pc, controllers, hardware

I'm newbie in gaming and and I have faced with some problems with shockers in gamepads. I have recently bought 2 cheap USB gamepads (microkingdom) for my children to play games on PC (windows 8.1), but one of our gamepads hardware is known ad joystick and the shocker works properly, but the other is known as gamepad and the shocker is not working.

[image]

I tried to uninstall drivers and install again but the problem still exists.
I also tried to install SPEEDLINK STRIKE version for settings but again the problem still exists.

how could I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you've bought two identical ones? Right now it looks as if both are using different generic drivers. So have you tried changing the non working ones driver to the one the working one uses, even if it's not shown as compatible?

Comment: @Mario, Yes they are identical, "So have you tried changing the non working ones driver to the one the working one uses"  How should I do this?

Comment: Right click start menu, pick "Device Manager", find the working controller, right click and pick the option to change drivers (or use the option in the device's properties), pick the manual option. Write down manufacturer and selected device name. Cancel the dialog. Go to the same place for the faulty controller and this time select/confirm the noted driver, untuck the compatibility option, if required.

Comment: If you have a xbox you can just sync your xbox controllers to your pc through bluetooth instead using the gamepads and you shouldn't have any problems with them.